# What is your favorite way to comment several lines in Vim?

Tags: vim, comments

It happens more often than not that I have to comment several lines at once in Vim. Methods that I know are not as fast as say TextMate way to comment lines out.

What is your favorite way to do it?

I currently use:

#### Method 1:

- go to first char of a line and use blockwise visual mode (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>)
- go down/up until the first characters of every lines you want to comment out are selected
- use <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> and then type your comment character (`#` for Ruby)
- use <kbd>esc</kbd> to insert the comment character to every line

#### Method 2:

- select lines you need to comment out using linewise visual mode (<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>)
- type `:` which gives you a `:'<,'>` prompt which you can extend to `:'<,'>s/^/#/`

#### Method 3:

- go to the first line to be commented out
- make a bookmark for example typing `mm`
- go to the last line to be commented out
- type `:'m,.s/^/#/`

I like method 1 the most but I still hope there is a better way.

Comment: I use `#if 0`/`#endif`, but probably that's not what you want ;-)

Comment: gms8994, type character and hit ESC.

Comment: This question pops up every once in a while: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584/in-vim-what-is-the-best-way-to-select-delete-or-comment-out-large-portions-of

Comment: How does someone without enough rep to vote for close bring a duplicate question to a moderator's attention? I've never had any luck with flagging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you described the most popular ways to comment code, but if you are open to use Vim Scripts, give a look to those:

- [The NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)
- [EnhCommentify.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23)
- [tComment](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)

Comment: These days tpope's [commentary.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) is another rather popular choice.

Answer (score 4):

I use a keymap for the regex part, but I do the same visual selection first.  Usually using:

```
vip
```

to get the visual block (paragraph visual selection)

then using

```
\cc
\co
```

for comment add/remove (cc,co chosen for muscle memory reasons)

with the mappings defined in .vimrc as:

```
vmap <leader>cc :s/^/#/<cr>
vmap <leader>co :s/^#//<cr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Though this is rather old I just wanted to add my solution which is pretty similar to everyone elses but adds the unhighlighting function. In my .vimrc file I have the following maps:

```
:vmap `c :s/^/\/*/<cr>gv:s/$/*\//<cr>:noh<cr>i
:vmap `r :s/^\/\*//<cr>gv:s/\*\/$/<cr>:noh<cr>i
```

Note: I use /*line of code*/ style of commenting to be compatible with old c code.
In vim I simply highlight the lines and push `c to comment and `r to remove comments.

Answer (score 1):

I normally just save the step in a macro and then invoke the macro in whichever fashion I feel like.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are the way to go. They are extensible, they already support more filetypes that you would ever use, they are automagically able to toggle the commented state of a line (in other words: no need to consume two shortcuts where one is enough).

See the [list given by CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883896/what-is-your-favorite-way-to-comment-several-lines-in-vim/1883940#1883940).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a set of commands for ANSI C one-line commenting and I've tried out most of the answers at SO.

None of them suit my needs and as I have to use an old 7.2 version of Vim at the moment and I cannot easily download suitable plugins I came up with these handy mappings:

```
:nnoremap <leader>c :exe "normal mqI/* "<esc> :exe "normal A */"<esc> :exe "normal 'q"<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>r ^xxx$xxx^
```

`<leader>c` comments out a line and goes back to the beginning of that line.

`<leader>r` removes the the comments from the beginning and the end of the current line.